# What kind of question are asked in Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer exam?

Tags: magento2, certification

> What kind of question are asked in Magento 2 Certified Associate
>   Developer exam ?

The exam is designed to validate the skills and knowledge of Magento 2 in the **areas** of

- **UI modifications**
- **database changes**
- **admin modifications**
- **customizations**
- **catalog and checkout structure**
- **functionality changes**

Then what kind of question are asked from above areas, just an idea will be enough so whoever appertaining for the exam can prepare accordingly.

Is Anyone appeared for the exam and have any idea regarding the same ?

Comment: https://www.goconqr.com/en-US/groups/81319 may be check here to get some idea

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have passed the M2 Associate Developer exam recently.
Question can not be remember as they are in multi line and hard to understand. The main point is question understanding. If you understand the question correctly, you get the answer easily.

You can check my profile below:

https://u.magento.com/certification/directory/dev/415007/

You can find the complete Exam_Study_Guide on magento website But swiftotter guide is very helpful.

https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-certified-associate-study-guide

**UI modifications:** This section will cover question based on block type, XML tags, my account section changes, theme and template hierarchy

**database changes:** This section will cover question based on sales and quote tables, relationship of products with categories

**admin modifications:** Admin controller, menu and ACL

**customizations:** all questions are based on business logic

**catalog and checkout structure:** all questions are based on business logic

**functionality changes:** all questions are based on business logic amd ask the best approach

Comment: Congrats Suman!

Comment: Can you send me a study guide?

Answer (score 9):

I passed the Associate Developer exam last night, here's my profile: https://u.magento.com/certification/directory/dev/3153044/.

I found that I had to read each question at least twice to get a 100% clear understanding of what they're asking - as Suman Singh says, each question tends to be quite long (2 or 3 lines in most cases) and provides a bit of background on the scenario.

The SwiftOtter practise test is worth doing to get your head in the mindset you'll need to take the exam. The questions are not exactly what you'd find in the exam, but are of a similar difficulty and are along the same lines. I got 78% on this practise test and got 84% in the actual exam, so it's a fairly good indication.

The biggest tip I can give you is to not rely just on reading material - you really need to get your hands dirty. With most of the questions, you can usually narrow the answers down to 2 potential right answers. The difference in these 2 answers might be as simple as one word, or one extra directory in a Controller path - this is where your practical experience becomes invaluable.

Good luck!

Comment: Congratulation on passing the exam :)

Comment: Congratulation David

Answer (score 0):

Question 1
You are building an extension that will be sold on the Magento Marketplace. This extension depends on Magento_Catalog. How is a Magento database upgrade performed?

A. Automatically when a new module version is detected

B. Manually on the CLI

C. Manually in the Admin UI

D. When the cache is cleared and the module change is pr

Question 2
You’re tasked with investigating a custom page layout declared in MyCompany/MyModule that isn’t loading. You’ve determined that this is the result of your XML configuration. Which 2 files do you investigate to locate the issue?

A. MyCompany/MyModule/view/frontend/layouts.xml

B. MyCompany/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/page.xml

C. MyCompany/MyModule/view/page_layout/custom.xml

D. MyCompany/MyModule/view/frontend/page_layout/custom.xml

Question 3
A merchant would like to manually specify the order of products per category. How is this done?

A. This requires a customization.

B. There is a position field on the category management page which allows you to define the order of a product in the category.

C. There is a position field on the product management page which defines a position of the product in all categories.

D. Custom ordering is disabled by default, but can be enabled in System Configuration.

Question 4
What happens when a customer adds two of the same simple products with different custom options to the cart?

A. They will be shown as one line item which lists both variations alongside their quantities.

B. An exception will be thrown because multiple variations of custom options for a simple product cannot be added to the cart.

C. They will be shown as two separate line items.

D. Magento will replace the first variation with the second one.

Answer Key
Question 1 Answer: B

Question 2 Answers: A and D

Question 3 Answer: B

Question 4 Answer: C

[image: Exam Guide]